# In Codenameone must I explicitly stop a Timer?

Tags: codenameone

If I create a timer with a runnable task, does it continue indefinitely once it is invoked? Does it stop when app is suspended or in background? Or is it required to explicitly stop timer and its tasks when app is being suspended?

Answer (score 1):

A `UITimer` will generally suspend in the background but a `Timer` won't. You should stop it because if the app tries to do something in the background without the right authority both iOS and Android will kill it for doing that.

If you want to do something specific in the background there are various supported use cases in iOS which you should align to.

Comment: How does one do this in Codenameone?

Comment: I'm also interested by this question. If I put all the code run by a `Timer` into a `CN.callSerially(...)`, is it enough to be sure that my app doesn't do anything when it is in background? Of course, in this case, I'm assuming that the code can be run inside the EDT.

Comment: There's background sections for each supported use case in the developer guide e.g. background location, background fetch, playback etc. @FrancescoGalgani no. Timer has its own thread and it keeps on running...